# Can't make ALB Health check working using @grpc/grpc-js NodeJS application deployed on ECS Fargate

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, cloud, grpc, aws-application-load-balancer

My gRPC NodeJS server uses @grpc/grpc-js and exposed the server using

```
const healthPackage = loadSync(path.join(__dirname, '/protos/health.proto'), {
  keepCase: true,
  longs: String,
  enums: String,
  defaults: true,
  oneofs: true,
});
const healthProto = grpc.loadPackageDefinition(healthPackage).grpc as any;
server.addService(healthProto.Health.service, {
  Check: checkHealth,
  Watch: watchHealth,
});

server.bindAsync(
  '127.0.0.1:50051',
  grpc.ServerCredentials.createInsecure(),
  () => {
    server.start();
    console.log('gRPC server started on 127.0.0.1:50051');
  },
);
```

I have defined health.proto that look like this

```
syntax = "proto3";

package grpc;

message HealthCheckRequest {
  string service = 1;
}

message HealthCheckResponse {
  enum ServingStatus {
    UNKNOWN = 0;
    SERVING = 1;
    NOT_SERVING = 2;
    SERVICE_UNKNOWN = 3;
  }
  ServingStatus status = 1;
}

service Health {
  rpc Check(HealthCheckRequest) returns (HealthCheckResponse);

  rpc Watch(HealthCheckRequest) returns (stream HealthCheckResponse);
}
```

I have tried setting the ALB group health check path `/grpc.Health/Check`, also set HTTPS listener rule to match that path and forward that to target group. The load balancer still fails and my grpc server not exposed. My server exposed on 50051 port. How can I resolve the health check path? Included the AWS settings screenshots.
[image]
[image]
[image]

I tried setting diffrent code on health check path. My code was returning serving status. My server also have Reflection implemented.

Comment: Are you using SSL? If I'm not wrong ALB with GRPC use HTTP/2 and is sort of mandatory to configure SSL in the balancer

Comment: Yes. That is configured.

Comment: [`@grpc/grpc-js`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@grpc/grpc-js) includes an implementation of [`grpc-health-check`](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node/tree/master/packages/grpc-health-check) of the gRPC [Health Checking Protocol](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/health-checking.md), so you can save yourself some work.You don't show how you're implementing/adding the service. You don't clearly show how you're configuring the LB to access it.

Comment: Hello @DazWilkin I've added more details you asked for. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Your code doesn't work. You've not defined `server`, `checkHealth` etc. I encourage you to read the gRPC docs and maybe have a look at the [examples](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node/tree/master/examples). You should not use localhost (`127.0.0.1`) as the endpoint (as this permits no external traffic).

Comment: I'll post an "answer" comprising working code for you to use as a basis.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unfamiliar with AWS|ALB but your LB config looks OK.

Your code doesn't work.

Here's a working example:

```js
const grpc = require("@grpc/grpc-js");
const protoLoader = require("@grpc/proto-loader");

const PROTO_PATH = `${__dirname}/protos/health.proto`;

const PORT = 50051;

const healthPackage = protoLoader.loadSync(
  PROTO_PATH, {
    keepCase: true,
    longs: String,
    enums: String,
    defaults: true,
    oneofs: true,
  },
);

const proto = grpc.loadPackageDefinition(healthPackage).grpc;

function checkHealth(call, callback) {
  console.log("[checkHealth] invoked");

  callback(null,{
    status: "SERVING",
  });
}

var server = new grpc.Server();
server.addService(proto.Health.service, {
  Check: checkHealth,
});


server.bindAsync(
  `0.0.0.0:${PORT}`,
  grpc.ServerCredentials.createInsecure(),
  () => {
    server.start();
    console.log(`gRPC server started on :${PORT}`);
  },
);
```

You can test this using [gRPCurl](https://github.com/fullstorydev/grpcurl):

1. Run the gRPC server

```bash
node index.js
```

```
gRPC server started on :50051
```

2. Test the `Check` method:

```bash
grpcurl \
-plaintext \
--proto health.proto \
:50051 \
grpc.Health/Check
```

```
{
  "status": "SERVING"
}
```

Comment: I didn't add checkHealth method to the question. The server is running fine and responding exactly the same as yours.

Comment: You would have saved us both time by including these facts in your question. There's a reasonable expectation that questions contain a minimally reproducible example of the issue.Since it appears that your application responds to health checks as expected, the issue appears to be with the LB config. Good luck!